# Bitcoins transaction is completed but I don't get the coins

Tags: copay

I got the bitcoins but it's not getting added to my wallet, I even got the email etc. and it shows up but see [this](http://prntscr.com/jh9zgt)

[image: Copay error message]

*Transaction is not available at this time*

Comment: Can you share the error message in English? If you check the address on an explorer, so you see your coins?

Comment: The error message says something like "Transaction could not be found." @Yuma can you share a txid (Transaction ID)?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction ID would be helpful to further diagnose what went wrong, however without that information, you can try the following:

**Refresh the transaction cache.**

- Go to "Settings" (gear icon)
- Choose the BCH wallet
- Go to "More Options"
- Choose "Transaction History"
- Choose "Clear Cache" to reset your transaction list.

Note that it will say 'Updating Wallet' until the list has been retrieved.

**Refresh the server's cache.**

- Go to "Settings" (gear icon)
- Choose the BCH wallet
- Go to "More Options"
- Go to "Wallet Addresses"
- Choose Scan addresses for funds

Note that it will say 'Scanning Funds' until the addresses have been scanned.

Answer (score 0):

check the [Bitcoin Block Explorer](https://blockexplorer.com/) on the transaction and/or your wallet to see what the status of the transaction is.